# android camera2 qrscanner qrcode scanner

Tags: android, android-studio, android-camera, qr-code, android-camera2

How to create qrcode scanner apps using android 6? Android 6 uses android.hardware.camera2 to access camera. If I have to update the entire ZXING library that would take very long time for a newbie like me. Is there any easy way to do it?

Comment: Whats wrong with ZXING library? I'm running Android 6 and it works fine.

Comment: You (and by extension ZXing) still have access to the older camera API on Marshmellow. Why not use that?

Comment: I used Nexus 5X running android 6. I used the old API android.hardware.Camera to access the camera. It breaks the applications. After I use the new android.hardware.camera2 API, it works fine. So thats why I can't use it anymore.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a third party library called **Zxing** .

You can add zxing library to your app via gradle dependency

just add this to your `build.gradle` file

```
compile 'com.google.zxing:core:3.2.1'
compile 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.0.3@aar'
```

Now in your onCreate method of your activity , do the following

```
 IntentIntegrator scanIntegrator = new IntentIntegrator(MainActivity.this);
 scanIntegrator.setPrompt("Scan a Barcode");
 scanIntegrator.setBeepEnabled(true); 
 scanIntegrator.setOrientationLocked(true);
 scanIntegrator.setBarcodeImageEnabled(true);
 scanIntegrator.initiateScan();
```

You can find a sample project [here](https://github.com/sshuvro58/BarCodeScanner)

Comment: I tried this. It almost work. well, basically because there is an exception for errors I guess so the APP doesn't breaks. It says: Sorry, the Android camera encountered a problem. You may need to restart the device. 

After this, I tried to run the camera (camera app from google) and it works fine. Also I tried the camera using camera2-basic and it also works fine.

Comment: try adding <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />  and set your target sdk version to 22

Comment: It works! Note: I have already put the <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" /> on the manifest. It still produce error. After I changed the target sdk from 23 to 22 on build.gradle it works. Why is that? And after this, I changed the target sdk from 22 to 23 again. And the APP works too. I can use zxing to scan qrcode. Why is that? Is it because my project was missing something that is not generated by the IDE when I use target SDK 23 and it was generated somehow when I use target SDK 22? This solves my problem thank you, but it doesn't answer the question.